# Edit element in browser with python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, attributes, element

How can I edit an element in a browser that I opened with Python 2.7 Selenium.
Let's say I have this element:

```
<span id="some-random-number">100</span>
```

I know that you can find the text with:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("some-random-number").text
```

but I want the text of the element change to let say 200 so:

```
<span id="some-random-number">200</span>
```

How can I do it? Also except from text can I also edit element's attribute like for example this:

```
<div class="something" style="transition: transform 1000ms bla bla bla"></div>
```

Can my script read the attribute and edit the 1000 ms into different value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is your answer -

1. Change the text of element -

   ```
   driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('some-random-number').innerHTML = '200';");
   ```

   or

   ```
           element =driver.find_element_by_id("some-random-number")
           driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = '200'", element)
   ```
2. Change or set an attribute value

   ```
           element =  driver.find_element_by_class_name("something");
           driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'transition: transform 2500ms bla bla bla')", element);
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
element =driver.find_element_by_id("some-random-number")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = '200'", element)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

```
div_elem = driver.some_method_to_find_element()
new_style = div_elem.get_attribute('style').replace('transform 1000ms', 'transform 200ms')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "%s")' % new_style, div_elem)
```