# How to go to some certain page# of a web site using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

There are 4000 pages of data in an given image of a website, [BscScan](https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3). Is there any way to directly go to on some certain page number say 1000 using Python? I only know a long way of doing it, i.e. go to page 1, 2, 3, 4, but it will take too much time to reach to page 1000.

[Web-page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmh0l.png)

Comment: From looking at the Network tab in firefox dev tools, it looks like they use AJAX to load each page. Have you tried making requests to the `https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=<addr>&m=normal&p=<page>` endpoint and parsing the output?

Comment: NO, I am new and don't know how to do it? Can you please guide me completing the task?

Comment: I add the address and page number copied it to browser, but it displays error: this is what I used https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3&m=normal&p=5

Answer (score 1):

After sniffing around the page I can see that there is a method to change the page via a URL.

1. Go to the page:
   https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3
2. View page source. Search for a `var` called `sid`. It will look like this: `var sid = '877a5d483a2d45460c42adf16029f473';`
3. Use that sid in the following URL: `https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3&a=&sid=PUTTHESIDHERE&p=1`
4. You will now be able to change the page by changing the page number (`p=1` in URL in step 3)

You can use this with Selenium to extract the data you need. You will need to utilize a headless browser as the SID is generated for each session.

You can extract the `sid` programmatically by utilizing a regex on the page source:

```
import requests
import re

sid = ""

def get_sid(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    pattern = re.findall(r"var sid = '[^']*", r.text)
    sid =  pattern[0].replace("var sid = '","")
    return sid
```

Comment: Thanks for the start. I am new in web-scrapping and not sure how to do it further. Can you please add some code to go directly on page 5.

Answer (score -1):

You already located the button, anyways

```
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@data-original-title="Go to Next"]/a')
```

Then change the address of the button ([Edit element in browser with python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553189/edit-element-in-browser-with-python-selenium)), specificly the last argument which is the page num, and finally

```
next_button.click()
```

Comment: I am not sure, how to edit, is it something like: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].page = '200'", next_button ). It is not working.